# Can't find my USB in /deb/tty* in a raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi, gps, usb, raspberry-pi3, uart

I'm trying to connect a GPS via USB to my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B. I have found lot of documentation to do this. What I can't do is the first step to work with my gps: find it in the dev/tty device list. I know I should get /dev/ttyUSB0 or something like that. However I only get the following devices:

However, my GPS module at least gets power from the raspberry, because when I connect it, its red led lights up.

I have tried connecting and disconnecting the usb, and I have used dmesg to see the kernel events, with no result.

I have also used lsusb, plug in and out, without success.

I want find it in anyway to work with my gps.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the Pi isn't able to supply enough power to the GPS module, best bet is to first try the module on another system, or to connect it through a powered USB-hub.

You should be able to see it when running `dmesg -w` and then plugging the module.